# How to make SafetyNet/Firebase AppCheck work in Google Play Pre-Launch Reports

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-check, safetynet, prelaunch

I'm using Firebase AppCheck to authenticate that calls to my API are indeed coming from my app.

My issue is that ever since I enabled AppCheck, I can only get a token on legit devices or via debug tokens for the emulator. In a way this makes sense, but being unable to take advantage of Pre-Launch Reports is a pretty big caveat since they come in handy to ensure I don't ship a bugged version to my testers. Neither Pre-Launch Reports nor the Firebase Test Lab seem to have a way to pass SafetyNet.

Are all apps that use SafetyNet just unable to use Pre-Launch Reports or the Firebase Test Lab? That seems rather implausible to me, which is why I assume I'm missing something here.

Relevant code:

`app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-safetynet:16.0.0-beta06'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-debug:16.0.0-beta06'

    // ...
}
```

In the `onCreate()` method of my `Application` class:

```
// ...

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)

val appCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance()

appCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(
    if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        SafetyNetAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance()
    } else {
        Log.i(javaClass.name, "Using debug version of AppCheck.")
        DebugAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance()
    }
)

// ...
```

Comment: Because SafetyNet will eventually be replaced with Play Integrity API, could you please also confirm that this is also an issue with the Play Integrity provider?

Answer (score 1):

you might want to create a debug token on your project portal and try the following code:

```
object AppCheckFactoryProvider {

    fun get(context: Context): AppCheckProviderFactory {
        return when {
            isRunningOnTestDevice(context = context) -> CIDebugAppCheckProviderFactory()
            BuildConfig.DEBUG -> DebugAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance()
            else -> PlayIntegrityAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance()
        }
    }

    private fun isRunningOnTestDevice(context: Context): Boolean {
        return Settings.System.getString(
            context.contentResolver,
            FIREBASE_TEST_LAB_SETTINGS
        ) == "true"
    }

    private const val FIREBASE_TEST_LAB_SETTINGS = "firebase.test.lab"
}

class CIDebugAppCheckProviderFactory : AppCheckProviderFactory {

    override fun create(firebaseApp: FirebaseApp): AppCheckProvider {
        return DebugAppCheckProvider(firebaseApp, BuildConfig.APP_CHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN_FROM_CI)
    }
}
```

After that, you can inject the secret debug token into your build.

NOTE: Don't forget to rotate the token so often or ideally after each release, once the release cycle once it can be acquired if you decompile the APK.

Comment: The signature of the constructor `DebugAppCheckProvider` is deprecated. Can you update your answer with the new constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for bringing this to our attention. The team is aware of the issue that apps with SafetyNet may not work correctly in Pre-launch Reports (PLR). However, [Play Integrity API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/overview), which is also supported by App Check, should be supported by PLR soon--and since Play Integrity will soon replace SafetyNet, please consider migrating to Play Integrity regardless. In the meantime, as a workaround, you could tell your app to bypass SafetyNet Attestation and use debug tokens ([similar to CI environments](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/debug-provider#ci)) if the app is running in Test Lab. To do this, see [Modify instrumented test behavior for Test Lab](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/android-studio#modify_instrumented_test_behavior_for).